# How can I find out total disk space occupied by a certain user?

Tags: perl

How can I find total disk space occupied by a certain user, say located in `/home/Mary`? What function is available in Perl to know this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl has [`Filesys::DiskUsage`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Filesys%3a%3aDiskUsage) for that. There is just one downside, it doesn't take the size of the directories while counting. Only the size of the files.

```
use Filesys::DiskUsage qw/du/;
$size = du ( { 'sector-size' => 1024 } , { 'human-readable' => 1 } , qw%/home/Mary% );
print "Total size: $size\n";
```

Comment: Quoting a path with `/` as its path separator with `qw` using `/` as the separator is somewhat unfortunate.

Comment: @rafl: Oops... my bad. My Perl is a little rusty ;)

Comment: Some more downsides include the fact that it doesn't handle sparse files correctly, nor can it automatically determine the block size of your filesystem.  Your system's `du` command is probably more accurate.

Comment: There's really no reason to use `qw` here at all.  The module's author just really likes `qw` for some reason and uses it in all the examples.  Regular quotes would work just as well and be more readable.

Answer (score 1):

if Perl is not a must, you can use shell commands

```
find /home -user "Mary" -type f -printf "%s\n" | awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum" bytes"}'
```

Comment: @user131527: in that case, why not simply call `du` instead?

Comment: @WoLpH, the problem is that, in /home/Mary, there may be files not belonging to Mary (don't ask me why)... using du is less "accurate". And using find with username is more flexible

Comment: @user131527: Agreed, it is slightly less acurate. But since users are normally not allowed to change the owner and creating a file automatically sets the user as an owner, the risk is negligible ;)

Comment: @WoLpH, sometimes, there may be files owned by root in the home directory, which either the user cannot read, or is read only user user. You will never know.